# Neanderthal living with us?

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a short story about neanderthals living quietly with us. I recall they were off-grid in urban areas. A charismatic male and partner.
Probably written in the 70's

Comment: Off-grid in urban areas? How does that work?

Comment: @amaranth Very poorly.

Comment: So not The Gnarly Man by Spague de Camp?

Comment: Please add more details; you can look [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) for some examples. Once you come up with more distinguishing features, [edit] your post to add them.

Comment: Gnarly Man doesn't seem to fit his description.  I seem to recall a story like this though.  I don't know that his partner was necessarily a neanderthal, and I believe they lived in a junkyard or something.  All my short-story anthologies are boxed in my garage, or I would see if I could find it.

Answer (score 11):

[The Alley Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Alley_Man) is a short story by Phillip Jose Farmer

Its about a junkman named Old Man Paley who may be the last Neanderthal alive.

He lives on the outskirts of a city with two women, earning a living by going through trash, when he is discovered by an grad student named Dorothy

Comment: This is the one I was thinking of; it is mentioned in the wikipedia article on Gnarly man.  [Here is the story](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/71734/4/Farmer_-_The_Book_of_Philip_Jose_Farmer.html)

Comment: This was the same one I thought of right away.

Comment: Great place to start! Thank you! I will check out my anthologies and the library.